# MS SQL connection with PHP fatal error

Tags: sql-server, installation, php

I use the following code for connecting php with MS SQL :

```
$server = 'a.b.c.d';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sql_user', 'sql_user_pass');
```

But it gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

How can I solve this?

Mention that I am using MS SQL (SQL SERVER 2008), PHP 5.3.1, WINDOWS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSSQL extension is not activated by default.

- Do a phpinfo() to find out which php.ini file is used by your PHP installation
- open that php.ini file
- uncomment the line saying `;extension=php_mssql.dll` (remove the semicolon)
- Restart the server if necessary

Answer (score 2):

“mssql” was dropped from PHP 5.3 distribution. Use sqlsrv drivers instead. You can find those at this link [PHP drivers for MS-SQL](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17308)